# Looking for official Apple sources mentioning Sidebars

Tags: ios, sidebar

Are there any official documents regarding Sidebars / Navigation Drawers or whatever they may call them, written by Apple? I know that there are no official Sidebar component - I am just looking for any mentioning of Sidebars in official Apple documents (whatever it may say). Want to know how Apple sees these sidebars and if they express any opinion about how and when to use them

Comment: They're not a UIKit element/idiom and, to my knowledge, are not used in any of Apple's own apps.

Comment: Apple definitely don't like them, there is a WWDC talk where they mention them. http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/06/30/apple-on-hamburger-menus

Comment: @beyowulf yes I pointed this out in the question.

Comment: @JamesP yes I recently found this document too and it states their oppinion. However, It's not an official document (or video)

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything more official than a WWDC video from Apple. There's nothing in the human interface guidelines, probably because they don't see them as a proper iOS UI element.

Comment: @Joakim It wasn't pointed out in the question I answered. But, are you like looking for Apple to send you a personal email saying don't use them? I think you can get the implications.

Comment: @JamesP no it's sufficient, but I can't find the video link (But I will)

Comment: @Beyowulf I don't think you got the question. I cannot see any references to personal emails in my question (Please point out if you do...) The question is asking for written sources from Apple regarding this design pattern. It's not asking for any "implied" hints from the fact that Apple doesn't provide it as a Standard component. I am looking for explicit material describing Apples opinion i.e whether they recomend to use or avoid them. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most official response I can find from Apple is in one of their WWDC talks where they explicitly mention Hamburger menus (or sidebars):

`"Their value is greatly overstated and they have huge usability downsides".`

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-211/
(around 31 mins)

There is nothing in the Human Interface guidelines about Hamburger menus, which in itself should imply that Apple doesn't rate them. As is stated in the video

```
"Typically we don’t provide design advice about the things that we don’t offer".
```

So although these UI elements may make sense for your app, Apple recommends other approaches to designing your UI and menus.